# Is it best to define the default value of a class attribute when declaring it or when constructing the object? [Java]

Tags: java

In other words, should I set the value in the constructor :

```java
public class Game {
    private int players;

    public Game() {
        this.players = 2;
    }
}
```

or set it as soon as the attribute is declared:

```java
public class Game {
    private int players = 2;

    public Game() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you have only an empty constructor? If you have more than one constructor, you may want to assign the value when declaring the attribute and change the value if needed in each constructor

Comment: There is no difference in the majority of cases.

Comment: Most of the time, I will only have one constructor which is not likely to be empty.

Comment: If there is no difference, I suppose it would be best to set it when declaring the attribute to remove one line of code.